# How can I add reloading gif image after changing the dropdown value in JSP page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have dynamic table on my JSP page, where I have added the rows to the table which depends on a dropdown field.

```
 This is my table code:
function createDynamicTable(data){   

            currentbatchitemData = eval(data);  

            for(var i = 0; i < currentbatchitemData.length; i++){

                    var code  = currentbatchitemData[i].empCode; 
                    var name  = currentbatchitemData[i].empName;    
                    var salary = 0 ;
                    var income = currentbatchitemData[i].incomeYear;
                    var month = currentbatchitemData[i].month ;
                    var des = currentbatchitemData[i].batchDesc;

                    var tableInfo = "<tr>";
                    tableInfo +=
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">' + code  + '</td>' +  
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">' + name  + '</td>' +
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">'+ salary + '</td>' +
                                '<td class="table-td-text-color">' + 
                                '<button type="button" class="btn-edit btn btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></button>'+
                                '<button type="button" onclick="delRow(this);" class="btn-del btn btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>' +'</td>';         

                    $("#currentbatchitem tbody").append(tableInfo);             
                }

             $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#currentbatchitem').DataTable();

            });

                $("#income_year").val(income);
                $("#pay_month").val(month);
                $("#batch_description").val(des);

}
```

I want when I have changed the dropdown , the page will be disabled and a gif image will be shown as a reloading image and when the for loop is terminated / after the adding rows on the table; the gif image will be hide and the jsp page will be shown again.
How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming you call createDynamicTable every time the dropdown changes, I guess you should 'turn on' a spinner gif and return Jquery promise from createDynamicTable and when it's done, you should 'turn off' the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using jQuery DataTables, there's a default option to show the processing indicator:

```
$('#currentbatchitem').dataTable( {
   "processing": true
} );
```

More details [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing)

PS: You can customize the message like so:

```
$('#currentbatchitem').dataTable( {
  "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": "DataTables is currently busy"
  }
});
```

If you want to instead show a loading GIF, you can override the CSS class like so:

```
 .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing{
    background-image:url('url/to/your/image.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a plain javascript solution

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createDynamicTable(){
            document.getElementById('loadingDiv').style.display = "block";

            //your for loop
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                document.getElementById('loadingDiv').style.display = "none";
            }, 2000);               
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="createDynamicTable();">
    Some page content
    <div id="loadingDiv" style="background-color: black; opacity: 0.50; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 100;">
        <img src="http://gifyo.com/public/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
    </div>
</body>
```